# Webdriver how to apply DesiredCapabilities

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver, nunit

The issue I am experiencing is that I am running my tests in multiple browsers but noticing significantly slower load times with Firefox. I am implementing the multiple browsers like so.

```
[TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))]
public class UnitTest1<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
{
    PTGeneral General;
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        General = new PTGeneral();
        General.Driver = new TWebDriver();
        General.PT_URL = "https://chi-pt-dev1.corp.auctiva.com/";
    }
```

What I need to do is make the default timeout time for the Firefox driver to something greater than 60 seconds.

When I use the this approach to initiate a the Firefox driver, everything works well.

```
General.Driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(), new FirefoxProfile(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

Is there any way for me to marry these two?

Or does anyone know what variable is getting set in the driver when I pass `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180)`? Is there away to change this value at run time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

It will allow you to change the timeouts as needed.